# Query LDAP for all entries without given objectClass

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have several entries in my LDAP directory with different object class specified

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com
uid: user1
objectClass: user
objectClass: developer
cn: User1 User

dn: uid=user2,ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com
uid: user2
objectClass: user
objectClass: administrator
cn: User2 User

dn: uid=user3,ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com
uid: user3
objectClass: user
objectClass: developer
objectClass: administrator
cn: User3 User

dn: uid=user4,ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com
uid: user4
objectClass: anotherClass
cn: User4 User
```

I want to query all that don't have objectClass: developer, regardless of other object classes they have.
I tried

```
ldapsearch -x -b ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com "(&(objectClass=*)(!(objectClass=developer)))"
```

but I got

```
dn: ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

What would be the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

As you have but without the & and the `(objectClass=*)` part.

You also need to specify a subtree search.

Comment: So something like ldapsearch -x -b ou=users,dc=exampleCompany,dc=com -s sub "(!(objectClass=developer))"